# how to export multiple sheets from multiples querys whit Laravel Excel?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-8, export-to-excel, laravel-excel

I need to create a report in excel in Laravel 8, with several specific queries, and each query is saved in a different excel sheet, the laravel excel documentation does not explain it.

Does anyone know how is the structure to do this?

i have this queries:

```
$cursosvigentes = Reporte::selectRaw('concat(users.firstSurname, " ", users.secondSurname) AS fullSurname, concat(users.firstName," ", users.secondName) AS fullName, users.documento, capacitaciones.capacitacion, capacitaciones.fi, capacitaciones.fv, datediff(capacitaciones.fv, ?) AS diff',[$date])
        ->join('users','capacitaciones.id_usuario','=','users.documento')
        ->whereRaw(' datediff(capacitaciones.fv, ? ) < ?', [$date, 30])
        ->whereRaw(' datediff(capacitaciones.fv, ? ) > ?', [$date, 0])->get();

    $datostrabajadores = User::select('documento')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Send different argument to Excel class.

**Controller:**

```
$customer = User::all();
$filterCustomer = User::all()->where()->get();
(new ExportExcel($customer))->download('users.xlsx');
(new ExportExcel($filterCustomer))->download('users.xlsx');
```

**ExportExcel class:**

```
class ExportExcel implements FromQuery
{
    private $users;
    private $capacitaciones;

    public function __construct($users, $capacitaciones)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->capacitaciones= $capacitaciones;

    }

    public function query()
    {
        return ;  // Any query that includes these users
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, I tried as you indicate and I could not do it, i have 2 tables called: "capacitaciones" and "users", i have 2 queries: $sqlcapacitaciones and $sqlusers, the model for "capacitaciones" its called "Reporte" and the model for "users" its called "User"

Comment: So, pass two arguments to constructor... I edited my answer